# Django - get_object_or_404() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm trying to create a page where I can delete an article using class based views. There is one problem, I am getting an error which says :

```
id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

here is the code :

**views.py**

```
class DeleteView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)
        article.delete()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/')

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        article = Article.objects.get(id=kwargs['id'])
        context = {"article": article}
        return render_to_response("delete.html", context, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

**template.html**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8">
<form action="{% url 'DeleteView' article.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" value="{{ article.views.id }}">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete">
</form>
</div>
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^delete/(?P<id>\d+)/$', DeleteView.as_view(), name="DeleteView"),
```

The faults are problably on : **the views** : *line 3* | **the template** : *line 2*

I am missing something but I couldn't figure it out. How can I get through this problem?

Comment: where is `article_id` defined in the form?

Comment: @Pynchia I edited my post, I replaced it with `article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)` and it gets me another error

Comment: In `post` method `article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)` you are passing Python built-in `id` not from kwargs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with your `post` method of `DeleteView`, there you are passing `id` which is a python [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#id) rather you need to get the `id` from `kwargs`:

Problem:

```
class DeleteView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id) # <--------
```

Solution:

```
class DeleteView(View):
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=kwargs['id']) # <--------
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the model class, so that the function knows what type of object it is trying to get.

```
article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=request.POST.get('article_id', ''))
```

Comment: I've already tried it but `article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=id)` gets me an error that says **id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)**

Comment: You still need to pass out the value of the id, just as you did originally.

Comment: I should've use kwargs['id'] insted of built in id, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

In `post()`, you're not passing the `id` kwarg, but you're passing the built-in function `id`. You need to use `kwargs['id']` instead, as you did in `get()`.